# Relation between Decay Rate and Annihilation Cross Section

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, scattering-cross-section

In particle kinematics and realistic observable, one typically works with scattering cross sections and decay rates.

If one has an expression for a decay rate for a particle of a certain type to decay into two particles, is there a relation between this and the expression for the annihilation cross section for two particles of that type to collide and annihilate into the same two particles which were produced in the decay?

Answer (score 0):

The relation exist only  in the [Feynman diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram) that are used to calculate processes in particle physics, not in the functions that model them . Feynman diagrams have strict mathematical rules that define a computation that will predict the decay rate and the scattering rate. It is the way the time and space axis are defined  for the calculation that decides whether one wants to calculate a scattering or a decay.